# Recursively override a rc file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh

This is similar to a .htaccess for directories.

I have following:

File: ~/.myapprc

```
APP_USER=alagu
APP_DOMAIN=goyaka.com
```

File: ~/testapp/.myapprc

```
APP_USER=alagu_test
APP_DOMAIN=localhost
```

What I want:

```
[alagu@~ ]$ echo $APP_USER
alagu

[alagu@~ ]$ cd ~/testapp
[alagu@~ ]$ echo $APP_USER
alagu_test
```

How do I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function in your `.bashrc` that overrides the `cd` command:

```
cd() {
    # "$@" to preserve quoting/whitespace
    builtin cd "$@"
    [ -f ".myapprc" ] && source .myapprc
}
```

Comment: Use `"$@"` instead of `"$*"` to avoid the quoting problems.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want to source `.myapprc` whenever you change directory.

There's two avenues you could use that I can think of - `PROMPT_COMMAND`, and the `DEBUG` trap.

To do this with the first, you'd run the following once:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="[ -f .myapprc ] && . .myapprc"
```

and with the second:

```
trap "[ -f .myapprc ] && . .myapprc" DEBUG
```

These will source the file once for every prompt, so if sourcing that file is expensive you could extend it to check if `$PWD` has changed.

You could also override `cd`, but this may break some shell scripts:

```
alias cd=cd_
function cd_
{
    \cd "$@"
    local ret=$?
    [ -f .myapprc ] && . .myapprc
    return $ret
}
```

**But doing any of these really isn't a good idea** - hey're all huge security holes since you'll end up running whatever commands are in `.myapprc` in whatever your current working dir is.

---

Late edit for Joachim - Use this with the `PROMPT_COMMAND`/`trap` solutions can avoid excessive execution of .myapprc with the following:
`PROMPT_COMMAND='if [ -f .myapprc -a "$PWD" != "$PWDLAST" ]; then PWDLAST="$PWD"; source .myapprc; fi'`

---

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your environment based on your working directory with direnv. It's at http://direnv.net .